# How to show whole numbers to 1 decimal point

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using the following formula to display results based on the answers obtained from another calculation. '=IF(A1<=10,MROUND(B1,0.1),IF(A1>10,MROUND(B1,1)))'.

The formula works with no issue, except for when the answer in A1 is less than 10, and the number in B1 is a whole number. I need the whole number to be displayed to 1 decimal place.

Any ideas?

Comment: This Formula? **=IF(A1<=10,MROUND(B1,0.1),IF(A1>10,MROUND(B1,1)))** but this formula doesn't make sense!

Comment: It would help if you would show some examples of what results you want from what input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have a *rounded **value**,*
that you can use for other calculations,
or is it good enough to *display* the desired number of digits? 
If the latter
(if it’s good enough to display the desired number of digits),
it may be easier to do this with formatting.

- Format cell `B1` (or the cells in Column `B`, if appropriate)
  as “Number” with 0 decimal places.
- With cell `B1` (or the cells in Column `B`) selected,
  click on “Conditional Formatting” → “New Rule”.
- Select “Use a formula to select which cells to format”.
- In the “Format values where this formula is true” box, enter `=A1<10`.
- Click on the “Format” button
  and specify a format of “Number” with 1 decimal place.